# Book about leprechauns, a war between two warlocks, and candles

Tags: story-identification, magic

There's a really good book I read back in 2007 that I can't remember the name of and have no idea how to find.

I only remember bits and pieces, so I'll list what I remember.

The book focused on a war between two warlocks (or something).

There's a guy that thinks that he can see a candle in peoples head. If the candle is lit, that means that they're alive, and if he blows out the candle they die.

There's a scene where he fights one of the magician, and he bangs on a wall and birds fly out of the wall.

It also explores ideas of mirror dimensions and gives detailed instructions on how to catch a leprechaun.

I think the guy also thought that he was going crazy, and then while living alone he started to think that maybe he wasn't.

It was a thick book.

That's all I really remember, I hope that's enough.

Comment: The candle bit sounds very familiar...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds a bit like [Jonathan Strange & Mr Norrell](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/14201.Jonathan_Strange_Mr_Norrell) by Susanna Clarke.

It follows the two title characters who are initially working together but later feud. There is some time given to trying to track/capture fairies.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Strange_%26_Mr_Norrell#Volume_III:_John_Uskglass) mentions a character using a mirror to move between locations in the 3rd act/part

Jonathon Strange definitely sees candles burning inside people's heads as he goes a bit insane towards the end.

> “May I ask you something?" Dr Greysteel nodded."Are you not afraid that
> it will go out?"
>
> "What will go out?" asked Dr Greysteel.
>
> "The candle," Strange gestured to Dr Greysteel's forehead. "The candle inside your head.”

(quote from https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/3921305-jonathan-strange-mr-norrell?page=2)

Comment: It certainly matches the criterion of being a "thick book"! :-)

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like it! Thanks! I'll go and grab it!